# How to access sub Class in different Package?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

In Package 1 i have Mainclass and SubClass. if in the package 2 How to access to Subclass?

If we want to access the subclass in same package but different file Java we can use such as:

```
  package Modifier;

        public class Other {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Public ut =  new Public();
     // Access the subclass of a class in the same package different file
            Public.subPublic sub_ut = ut.new subPublic();
        sub_ut();
        }
    }
```

But how to access the subclass of a Class in the different Package? Thanks...

Comment: You import it...

Comment: You didn't tell us what access modifiers these classes have.

Comment: What are the declarations of `Mainclass` and`SubClass`?  When asking questions you must include all the relevant code.

Comment: Are you talking about a subclass or an inner class? `ut.new subPublic()` is the syntax for instantiating an inner class from a location that isn't an instance method inside the outer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's doesn't make sense, but if you want to do this . check your access modifiers ,you must to use public :

```
public class Public{
public class subPublic{ //modify  access modifiers
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner class access is no different than access to fields or methods. You can use public, protected, package, or private access modifiers for an inner class.